# How to test instanceof on a generic class?

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

I have an `equals()` method that contains this code:

```
if (other instanceof Peach<K, V>) {
    ...
}
```

However, this does not compile. How to fix this line of code?

Comment: `instanceof` is a runtime comparison. Generics are a compile-time constraint that do not exist at runtime. You can only do `other instanceof Peach`.

Comment: FWIW, I can't ever remember a situation where what you're proposing was necessary. I *very rarely* need `instanceof` at all, let alone with reified generics. If you need to rely on this, your design is almost certainly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out, this is not possible. I would like to add that this is because of what is known as [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The official Java tutorial has the following short summary:

> Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type checks at compile time and to support generic programming. To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.
>
> Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.

The key here is *"The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods."*. Because of this, it is not possible, to do the `instanceof` check you seek to do.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't. Java erases generics types, so, at runtime, you don't have this information anymore.

You can use

```
if (other instanceof Peach) {
    ...
}
```